# Are there any mill/scala-3/scala.js examples available?

Tags: scala, scala.js, scala-3, mill

Is there a guide or example somewhere for using mill build tool with scala-3 and scala.js? I saw that the same question had been asked, but implicitly for sbt, and the answer was essentially "it just works". In mill I change the scalaVersion from 2.13.7 to 3.1.2 and learn that "resolution fails for org.scala-js:scalajs-library_sjs1_3:2.6.0".  It isn't clear to me the resolution that implies.

Comment: Is that on the latest version of Mill? The problem is that it is looking for `scalajs-library_sjs1_3`, but it should be looking for `scalajs-library_sjs1_2.13`. Also, the 2.6.0 version is very suspicious. The latest version of Scala.js as of this writing is 1.13.2.

Comment: Can you post your `build.sc`?

Answer (score 0):

The mill documentation includes a page on [scala.js](https://mill-build.com/mill/Web_Build_Examples.html#_scala_js_modules). As far as I know, it shouldn't matter that it's scala3

Example from the docs:

```
import mill._, scalalib._, scalajslib._

object foo extends ScalaJSModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.13.8"
  def scalaJSVersion = "1.13.0"
  def ivyDeps = Agg(ivy"com.lihaoyi::scalatags::0.12.0")
  object test extends ScalaJSTests {
    def ivyDeps = Agg(ivy"com.lihaoyi::utest::0.7.11")
    def testFramework = "utest.runner.Framework"
  }
}
```